# Mailx command attachment style is different between platforms

Tags: ubuntu, centos, mailx

On a virtual ubuntu box the mailx command has `-a` refers to the content headers and `-f` adds attachments. Whereas on my school's virtual machines (I think they run centOS) `-a` adds attachments.

I tried installing both `bsd-mailx` and `mailutils` but both had `-a` as referring to the content headers.

Is it the case that I am installing the wrong mailx package or there are different mailx versions?

How can I rectify this discrepancy so that it is the same across all distros? Is there a specific version of mailx that I should be installing or a particular reason they have different arguments?

edit: `-f` actually does something related to a mailbox location.

Comment: `dpkg-query -L mailutils | grep mailx` shows nothing so it means it
doesn't ship `mailx`. `man /usr/share/man/man1/bsd-mailx.1.gz` indeed
says that `-a` specifies additional headers. You should install
`heirloom-mailx` and run `man /usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz`
- this one says that `-a` adds an attachment. Not adding this as an answer because honestly I'm not sure I understand your question.